# Retrofit java.net.SocketTimeoutException

Tags: android, retrofit

Retrofit Call:

```
 RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
        .setEndpoint("BASE URL")
        .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
        .setClient(new OkClient(getOkHttpClient()))
        .build();
```

Dependencies:

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
```

Error:
user_id=XXXX&item_id=X&item_quantity=1&item_cost=XXXX&pay_id=stripe&process_fee=XXX&total_cost=XXX&is_nagotiation=0&negotiate_id=&tips=XXX&card_id=XXXX

> 09-07 11:45:08.628 23473-24373/com.bridgellc.bridge D/Retrofit: --->
>   END HTTP (177-byte body) 09-07 11:45:18.635
>   23473-24373/com.bridgellc.bridge D/Retrofit: ---- ERROR http:XXXXXX
>   09-07 11:45:18.650 23473-24373/com.bridgellc.bridge D/Retrofit:
>   java.net.SocketTimeoutException

Comment: Explain question properly. When are you getting this error? What solution you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set a timeout for your **OkHttp2** Client. First create an **OkHttp2** client,

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
client.setConnectTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
client.setReadTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
.build();
```

Then add it as the default client to the **Retrofit**

```
RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
.setEndpoint("BASE_URL")
.setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
.setClient(client).build();
```

Comment: Retrofit default Okclient connection timeout is 10 sec.but I am changed that connection time values are 20 sec same like your method.  RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(AppConstants.BASE_URL)
            .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
            .setClient(new OkClient(getOkHttpClient()))
            .build();

Comment: //Ok client Waiting time customize                                                    private OkHttpClient getOkHttpClient() {
        final OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
        okHttpClient.setReadTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        okHttpClient.setConnectTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        return okHttpClient;
    }

Comment: Where did you change the timeout value? Did you try the code I suggested?

Comment: client Waiting time customize private OkHttpClient getOkHttpClient() { final OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient(); okHttpClient.setReadTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS); okHttpClient.setConnectTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS); return okHttpClient; } –

Comment: Can you try with a large timout value? Let's say, 120 sec ?

Comment: @PrithivDharmaraj did you find solution?

Comment: yes, I got @Prokash Sankar and Thanks.I am increased  time out pried

Comment: and one more doubt can you help me @ProkashSarkar

Comment: could you read below question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39403950/how-to-clear-old-badge-count-in-android

Comment: This is absurd and weird. What kind of an answer is this. It is entirely misleading to a person looking for a reason and hence resolution. The question was about SocketTimeout problem and the answer was to keep increasing the socket time out value till the error is not encountered? Thats ridiculous. What if the device is not connected to the internet or if internet is not available? In such cases, even if you keep 10,000 secs timeout error will be encountered. Answer should have concentrated on the root cause. This is not an answer but a work around to a one use-case where it works.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on various factor one of those is timeout like `connectionTimeout` etc.If your server is not responding within timeout it will throw `SocketTimeoutException`. you can try increasing default `timeout` of `okhttp`

```
private static OkHttpClient okClient() {
        return new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .connectTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .writeTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .readTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .build();
    }
```

and set it to `Retrofit` instance.

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Util.APP_UPDATE)
                .client(RestClient.okClient())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .build();
```

Comment: ".addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))"  is not supported                                                                                         Dependencies:
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'

Comment: I am not using "compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'" i am using "compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'" both are different

Comment: This is just reference on setting custom Ok client to retrofit instance same you can set it to RestAdapter in case of 1.9.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this issue by adding `android:vmSafeMode="true"` in the Android configuration file.
There is discussion on the above problem can be found in github.
https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/1771
https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/1518#issuecomment-87996760

Comment: android:vmSafeMode="true" already i mentioned that code in my manifest file.