# How to clear old badge count in android

Tags: android, count, badge

I set "0" means its showing badge count was "1". how to clear my old badge count.

//Badge count set method

```
  public static void setBadge(Context mContext, int count) {
    String launcherClassName = getLauncherClassName(mContext);
    if (launcherClassName == null) {
        return;
    }
    Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.BADGE_COUNT_UPDATE");
    intent.putExtra("badge_count", count);
    intent.putExtra("badge_count_package_name", mContext.getPackageName());
    intent.putExtra("badge_count_class_name", launcherClassName);
    mContext.sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

//Find out our app and here return app package name.

```
 public static String getLauncherClassName(Context mContext) {

    PackageManager pm = mContext.getPackageManager();
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    List<ResolveInfo> resolveInfos = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
    for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resolveInfos) {
        String pkgName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.packageName;
        if (pkgName.equalsIgnoreCase(mContext.getPackageName())) {
            String className = resolveInfo.activityInfo.name;
            return className;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: why would you show any count if it is 0?

Comment: not zero. I would like to clear my old badge count. just i am checking with zero value we given means what will show like that i am checking and some scenario i need to clear my badge count. Eg)logged in user have 5 badged count . that current user is logout or blocked from admin like that scenario i would like clear old user badge count.

Comment: Hello did you figure this out ? I have the same problem

Answer (score 1):

This can be done if using the https://github.com/leolin310148/ShortcutBadger library by calling the method as follows:

```
ShortcutBadger.applyCount(Context context, int badgeCount)

//or

ShortcutBadger.removeCount(Context context)
```